# airflow timeout error for SSH operator while executing a docker image

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api, airflow-taskflow

Getting error of time-out for the task of SSH while executing the docker image and its commands within it.

```
[2023-06-14, 16:07:03 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1776} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 173, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command, context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 159, in run_ssh_client_command
    ssh_client, command, timeout=self.cmd_timeout, environment=self.environment, get_pty=self.get_pty
  File "/home/airflow/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 547, in exec_ssh_client_command
    raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH command timed out
```

How this can be resolved. We have already increased OS level timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the `cmd_timeout` is not set on your site.

Currently, I'm using Airflow 2.5.3 with `airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh` version 3.5.0. According to the documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/3.5.0/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh/index.html), there is a field name `cmd_timeout` which default to 10 second only. To solve the error, which throwing from SSHHook

```
  File "/home/airflow/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 547, in exec_ssh_client_command
raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
```

We need to set `cmd_timeout=None` or `cmd_timeout=300` to the SSHHook. E.g.

```
ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="ssh", cmd_timeout=None)
```

This solution works for me, hopefully, it is helpful.

**`None` means unlimited*